# Separate registration page in WooCommerce website

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Can anybody help me build a separate registration page in WooCommerce instead of displaying it in the `my-account` page?

In the `my-account` page I want to display a link which will take the buyer to the registration page.

Comment: How exactly you want to build the separate registration page? Some more information will be helpful.

Comment: @maksbd19 the registration page contains some text fields like name, email, password, retype password ect. and the my-account page contain login form and a register button only.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

edit your `form-login.php` file and seperate the login form and registration form in two different sections say section A and B.

now check for a `GET` parameter in the page which will define which section to show. By default login will be shown, if parameter is found and is "register", show registration section

```
if( isset( $_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == "register"){
    // Section for registration
}else {
    // Section for Login form
}
```

you can provide a link for registration as

```
<a href="' .get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('myaccount')). '?action=register"> register </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Code for form-login.php

is

--- START SECTION ---

```
<?php
/**
 * Login Form
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.2.6
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

?>

<?php wc_print_notices(); ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_customer_login_form' ); ?>

<?php if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_myaccount_registration' ) === 'yes' ) : ?>

<div class="col2-set" id="customer_login">

    <div class="col-1">

<?php endif; ?>

        <h2><?php _e( 'Login', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

        <form method="post" class="login">

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_login_form_start' ); ?>

            <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="username"><?php _e( 'Username or email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="input-text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) echo esc_attr( $_POST['username'] ); ?>" />
            </p>
            <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="password"><?php _e( 'Password', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input class="input-text" type="password" name="password" id="password" />
            </p>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_login_form' ); ?>

            <p class="form-row">
                <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-login' ); ?>
                <input type="submit" class="button" name="login" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Login', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
                <label for="rememberme" class="inline">
                    <input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever" /> <?php _e( 'Remember me', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
                </label>
            </p>
            <p class="lost_password">
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wp_lostpassword_url() ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Lost your password?', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
            </p>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_login_form_end' ); ?>

        </form>

<?php if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_myaccount_registration' ) === 'yes' ) : ?>

    </div>

    <div class="col-2">

        <h2><?php _e( 'Register', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

        <form method="post" class="register">

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start' ); ?>

            <?php if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_username' ) ) : ?>

                <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
                    <label for="reg_username"><?php _e( 'Username', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="input-text" name="username" id="reg_username" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) echo esc_attr( $_POST['username'] ); ?>" />
                </p>

            <?php endif; ?>

            <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="reg_email"><?php _e( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="email" class="input-text" name="email" id="reg_email" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['email'] ) ) echo esc_attr( $_POST['email'] ); ?>" />
            </p>

            <?php if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) ) : ?>

                <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
                    <label for="reg_password"><?php _e( 'Password', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input type="password" class="input-text" name="password" id="reg_password" />
                </p>

            <?php endif; ?>

            <!-- Spam Trap -->
            <div style="<?php echo ( ( is_rtl() ) ? 'right' : 'left' ); ?>: -999em; position: absolute;"><label for="trap"><?php _e( 'Anti-spam', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label><input type="text" name="email_2" id="trap" tabindex="-1" /></div>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form' ); ?>
            <?php do_action( 'register_form' ); ?>

            <p class="form-row">
                <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-register' ); ?>
                <input type="submit" class="button" name="register" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Register', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
            </p>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_end' ); ?>

        </form>

    </div>

</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_customer_login_form' ); ?>
```

--- END SECTION ---

Whet can i put this snippet :

--- START SECTION ---

```
if( isset( $_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == "register"){
    // Section for registration
}else {
    // Section for Login form
}
```

--- END START

and this URL

--- START SECTION ---

```
<a href="' .get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('myaccount')). '?action=register"> register </a>
```

--- END SECTION ---

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the code to have separate registration and login pages via individual links in the header.

You will need to edit 2 files in your child theme:

1. `functions.php` and
2. `form-login.php`

I have attached txt files for the code

1) **functions.php**: You want to create a register link in the header that links to the login page but also sets an action indicating you have clicked register.
So this:

```
$aux_links_output .= ''. __("Login", "swiftframework") .''. "\n";
```

becomes this:

```
$aux_links_output .= ''. __("Login", "swiftframework") .''. "\n";
$aux_links_output .= ''. __("Register", "swiftframework") .''. "\n";
```

2) **form-login.php** code:
Here you want to create an if,else statement. If you clicked register then goto register page, else goto login page:

```
<?php if( isset( $_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == "register") : ?>
```

Section for registration

```
<?php else : ?>
```

Section for Login form

```
<?php endif; ?>
```

Be careful of the wrappings

Thanks