# Prevent automatic login when register in woocommerce and redirect to login page?

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, woocommerce

I am designing a website with woo commerce wordpress I have separate the login and register page by reference to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23821488/separate-registration-page-in-woo-commerce-website/243046300)

How can I redirect the registration page to login page after successful registration without logged in. The user need to login there with the emailed username and password.

my login page is

www.example.com/my-account/

and registration page is

www.example.com/my-account/?action=register

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After a lot of search I found the solution for this

Step1: add [WP Approve User](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-approve-user/)

Step2: add these code to ur theme function file

```
/* Stop auto login */


function user_autologout(){
       if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
                $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
                $user_id = $current_user->ID;
                $approved_status = get_user_meta($user_id, 'wp-approve-user', true);
                //if the user hasn't been approved yet by WP Approve User plugin, destroy the cookie to kill the session and log them out
        if ( $approved_status == 1 ){
            return $redirect_url;
        }
                else{
            wp_logout();
                        return get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('myaccount')) . "?approved=false";
                }
        }
}
add_action('woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'user_autologout', 2);
function registration_message(){
        $not_approved_message = '<p class="registration">Send in your registration application today!<br /> NOTE: Your account will be held for moderation and you will be unable to login until it is approved.</p>';
        if( isset($_REQUEST['approved']) ){
                $approved = $_REQUEST['approved'];
                if ($approved == 'false')  echo '<p class="registration successful">Registration successful! You will be notified upon approval of your account.</p>';
                else echo $not_approved_message;
        }
        else echo $not_approved_message;
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_customer_login_form', 'registration_message', 2);
```

Comment: `wp_redirect( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_registration_redirect', $redirect ) );`
This line of code I got from `woocommerce/includes/class-wc-form-handler.php` line no 905.
I just suprised with your answer. How you can use add_action

Comment: @MakarandMane - while it is technically correct that this should use add_filter, add_action will actually still work.  add_action is essentially a wrapper for add_filter - it calls add_filter and returns the result.  That's why this answer would still work even though add_action was used.  Regardless, for such a small change it would be better to edit the answer than to apply an entirely new one that is exactly the same except for that one minor detail.

Answer (score 4):

Below line of code is located at `woocommerce/includes/class-wc-form-handler.php` line no 905.

`wp_redirect( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_registration_redirect', $redirect ) );`

I correcting answer given by @user3518270

Below line will not work as it is filter used by woocommerce So need to use add_filter() instead of add_action()

```
add_action('woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'user_autologout', 2);

/* Stop auto login */


function user_autologout(){
       if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
                $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
                $user_id = $current_user->ID;
                $approved_status = get_user_meta($user_id, 'wp-approve-user', true);
                //if the user hasn't been approved yet by WP Approve User plugin, destroy the cookie to kill the session and log them out
        if ( $approved_status == 1 ){
            return $redirect_url;
        }
                else{
            wp_logout();
                        return get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('myaccount')) . "?approved=false";
                }
        }
}
add_filter('woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'user_autologout', 2);

function registration_message(){
        $not_approved_message = '<p class="registration">Send in your registration application today!<br /> NOTE: Your account will be held for moderation and you will be unable to login until it is approved.</p>';
        if( isset($_REQUEST['approved']) ){
                $approved = $_REQUEST['approved'];
                if ($approved == 'false')  echo '<p class="registration successful">Registration successful! You will be notified upon approval of your account.</p>';
                else echo $not_approved_message;
        }
        else echo $not_approved_message;
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_customer_login_form', 'registration_message', 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `woocommerce` filter to prevent authentication.

Add this snippet to you functions.php file in child theme:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_auth_new_customer', '__return_false' );
```

Comment: Work perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using cookie,

function.php

```
setcookie('afterRegister', null, -1, '/');
function user_autologout(){
   if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
      wp_logout();
      setcookie("afterRegister", "afterRegister", time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
      return get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('myaccount'));

   }
}
add_filter('woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'user_autologout', 2);
```

page-my-account.php

```
<?php if(isset($_COOKIE["afterRegister"]) && !empty($_COOKIE["afterRegister"]) ) {?>
<div class="woocommerce-message" role="alert">
Your account has been created successfully, Please login using the auto generated password we've sent on your email address</div>
<?php }
```