# Wordpress | Woocommerce custom registration form

Tags: php, wordpress, passwords, woocommerce, registration

I would like to ask whether it is possible to create the registration with the only code that is sent to the user's mail after form submitted, I'm not sure how to do properly.

> for example : The user enters his email and the system will
>   automatically send the generated password example: " 12345 " And this
>   password i want use for all users

```
<?php
function wcs_filter_password_email( $args ) {
    $args['user_pass'] = $args['user_email'];
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_new_customer_data', 'wcs_filter_password_email' );
```

I found this code but do not know if it would work as I want it
**Thank you very much for your help.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example will give the user email for password. you need:

```
<?php
function wcs_filter_password_email( $args ) {
  $args['user_pass'] = "12345";
  return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_new_customer_data', 'wcs_filter_password_email' );
?>
```

Put it in your functions.php and it should work.
Don't forget to set the password to be auto generated from `WooCommerce > Settings > Accounts` otherwise the user will be asked to provide a password.

Comment: Thank you!Work perfectly

Comment: I have one more problem, but I dont want  bother :D

Comment: It's possible load woocommerce products into the user profile? For example
User logged in their profile see products and if he want order product... can order in they profile... sorry for english :D

Comment: yes, go to the page that is responsible for the user profile and add this shortcode in the end: [recent_products per_page="12" columns="4"] modify it according to your needs

Comment: I can have one more question? How to disable automatic login at registration?

Comment: check this question that has answer for what you want, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24379214/prevent-automatic-login-when-register-in-woocommerce-and-redirect-to-login-page also please consider upvoting the answer if it was helpful

Comment: Yes... very helpful! Thanks so much