# Prevent Auto login when register in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to moderate the customer even after payment. Once a user checkout using their info they automatically logged in. I want to moderate user signup.

I am using this plugin “New User Approve” but still no luck.

I want the user to log out after the registration.

I've tried the answer given here by Lipsa
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24486913/11549335

Comment: Please elaborate more your question

Comment: I would like to moderate the customer even after payment. But once a user fills in any information its acts like this:

1. User registers
2. WooCommerce automatically logs them in*

Comment: Please update your original post including those details