# How to create separate log-in and registration pages in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to seperate the login and registration page for woocommerce.
(there is a different solution that I don't get to work here:
[Separate registration page in WooCommerce website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23821488/separate-registration-page-in-woocommerce-website))

I duplicated the form-login.php and renamed it to register.php
In the register.php template I deleted the login-content.

I want to add a page to wordpress and add the register.php template with a SHORTCODE to that page. How do I do this??

Then I could add a Register Link to the Login Page with

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink(put the ID of the registerpage here) ?>"><?php _e( ' Register' ); ?></a>
```

and the new shortcode register page is loaded.
mmmhhh...

what do I have to add to the duplicated login /now register.php, that it can be loaded to any page with a SHORTCODE? that would be interesting.

Thanks for helping out!Best wishes, Mika

Answer (score 6):

A more straightforward way to do this is to save the contents of the original `form-login.php` as `form-login-single.php`, and then replace the file `form-login.php` with:

```
<?php
if( isset($_GET['action']) == 'register' ) {
    wc_get_template( 'myaccount/form-register.php' );
} else {
    wc_get_template( 'myaccount/form-login-single.php' );
}
```

This way you don't need to modify your `functions.php` further, plus you don't run into any trouble with double-rendering of the register form that I got when using @Hassan-ALi's method.

Comment: what is double rendering. is it same as reflow in dev tools?

Comment: I'll up vote for your answer, but how to do after to separate the two forms and that it redirects automatically to the register page or the login page, and also how to get the link for the register page! Should I activate "Allow customers to create an account on the My account page" on the woocommerce administration?

Comment: @GilbertOOl, Have you found the solution?

Comment: No sorry, actually I just keep login and register form on the same page!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a copy of the Woocommerce form-login.php and name it form-register.php. The form-login.php is located in /woocommerce/templates/myaccount/ folder.

Then in the form-login.php you can create a link to the form-register.php using this code

```
<a href="' .get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('myaccount')). '?action=register"> register </a>
```

```
// Separete Login form and registration form

add_action('woocommerce_before_customer_login_form','load_registration_form', 2);
function load_registration_form(){
    if(isset($_GET['action'])=='register'){
        woocommerce_get_template( 'myaccount/form-registration.php' );
    }
}
```